# Let $a=5^{\large \log_5(\sin x)}$ and $b=7^{\large \log_7(\cos x)}$ then $\frac ab$ can be equal to :

Tags: trigonometry, logarithms, exponential-function

> Let $a=5^{\large \log_5(\sin x)}$ and $b=7^{\large \log_7(\cos x)}$ then $\frac ab$
> can be equal to :
>
> $(a)\tan 2^{\circ}\qquad\qquad(b)\tan 4^{\circ}\qquad\qquad(c)\tan
>  5^{\circ}\qquad\qquad(d)\tan 1^{\circ}\qquad\qquad$

I know $m^{\large\log_nk}=k^{\large\log_nm}$, for $\quad m,k,n>0$.

Hence we have
$a=\sin x\quad $ and  $\quad b=\cos x$ where $x\in(2k\pi\;,\;2k\pi+\frac{\pi}2)$. And I think all the four choices can be correct because if we change the degree to the radian all the angles lie on $(0,\frac {\pi}2)$. I don't know what I am missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using $a^{\log_ab}=b$ we obtain $\tan x$.

Comment: Ok I just realized it was a multiple correct choice type of problem and all the choices are correct ! At first I thought there is only one correct answer.

Comment: @MasterShifu Actually, a very poorly worded problem.  There is a general convention that unless otherwise specified, only one choice can be correct.  For example, you will often see such problems that include (for example) [e] None of the Above, [f] Choices a and b only...